# Footer content not shown in responsive view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, web-frontend

I have try this code. Footer file is attached in every pages, in desktop view footer content show but in the responsive it shows only the following result **STL | All Rights Reserved.**

````html
```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="res-footer col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <p><span class="fa fa-copyright"></span><a href="/index">STL</a> | All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
```
````

Comment: Please provide your full code, including the CSS you use.

Comment: Can you share your e-mail so that i can send u my code.